# How to use PHP readdir to read files in directories outside of the root level and link?

Tags: php

I am using a php include (side nav menu- where php script would be) that resides on the root level of my webserver.

I would like to use a php readdir or scandir to list the contents of a different folder on my server (/report_1) with links to those files excluding html, htm and xslt extensions. (or to just only include php extensions)

Currently I am using a readdir that only reads the contents of the current directory it resides in and returns links excluding certain file types.(see code below)

I would eventually like to have a php file in the include that lists and links to files outside the "include" root level. Any help would be very appreciated.

```
<?php

// These files will be ignored
$excludedFiles = array (
'excludeMe.file',
'excludeMeAs.well'
);

// These file extensions will be ignored
$excludedExtensions = array (
'html',
'htm',
'php'
);

// Make sure we ignore . and ..
$excludedFiles = array_merge($excludedFiles,array('.','..')); 

// Convert to lower case so we are not case-sensitive
 for ($i = 0; isset($excludedFiles[$i]); $i++) $excludedFiles[$i] =         
strtolower(ltrim($excludedFiles[$i],'.'));
 for ($i = 0; isset($excludedExtensions[$i]); $i++) $excludedExtensions[$i] =     

strtolower($excludedExtensions[$i]);

// Loop through directory
$count = 0;
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
  $extn = explode('.',$file);
  $extn = array_pop($extn);
  // Only echo links for files that don't match our rules
  if (!in_array(strtolower($file),$excludedFiles) &&    

!in_array(strtolower($extn),$excludedExtensions)) {
    $count++;
    print("<a href=\"".$file."\">".$file."</a><br />\n");
  }
}
echo '<br /><br /><a href="..">Return</a>';
closedir($handle);
}

?>
```

Comment: So, what is your question? Where are you stuck? You can access the parent directory using `..` - is that what you are looking for?

Comment: The php code would be in the include that lists the files in other directories outside of the include.

Answer (score 1):

- Make the directory loop a function.
- Check if the current file is a directory using is_dir
- If it is, re-run that directory through the same function.
- Otherwise print the file name as you are doing.

You might want to consider using absolute paths in your links.

Hope this helps.